# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directo ry while launching sysmon

Tags: python

I got the error given below ,While launching the sysmon in Linux :

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/sysmon", line 5, in 
from sysmon.sysmon import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sysmon/sysmon.py", line 1, in 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directo ry"

I have installed the following packages with the command "pip3 install sysmon --force"

numpy -version 1.19.5,
,pip -version 21.2.4
,PyQt5 -version 5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5 -version 5.15.2
,PyQt5-sip -version 12.9.0
,pyqtgraph -versin 0.11.1
sysmon -version 1.0.1

Please anyone can help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't have ffmpeg installed because libGL.so.1 is part of ffmpeg
for install ffmpeg you can use:
Ubuntu: `sudo apt install ffmpeg`
Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S ffmpeg`
and for other distros search in package manager of that distro you can find ffmpeg

Comment: It really helped me. I installed RPM Fusion and ffmpeg then, import error got resolved. But    qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb. Aborted    -this error raised now . Please tell me your suggestions to fix this issue.

Comment: if im not wrong you missing libxcb too.
install libxcb with package manager.
i think it will be fixed